# How to change delimiter of md5sum command output

Tags: bash, unix

My code looks like this:

```
for i in `find` ; 
do
    if [ -f $i ]; then
        if [ "$i" != "./ex.sh" ]; then
            md5sum $i >> checksums.txt;
        fi
    fi
done
```

The problem is I want to use awk on the file later with a "|" as the delimiter. However I don't know how to append to file checksums.txt with a "|" between the md5sum and the $i.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
md5sum  $i | tr -s " " | tr " " "|" >> checksums.txt
```

Comment: Then you could just use sed to replace the first space with a `|`. Like this: `sed 's/ /|/'`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail agree, its time for people to stop using spaces in file names.

Comment: @Lynch +1, if the filename has spaces, you'll have to use sed instead of tr.

Comment: At minimum you could `md5sum "$i"`, to at least try to have an *appearance* of an attempt at robustness.

Answer (score 1):

Including this question, I've read at least 3 questions from you regarding the same problem. I guess you want to find all duplicated files under some directory, right?

then you can try the one liner below, it would save your later looping or double looping and awk processing:

```
find {what you want to find comes here} -exec md5sum '{}' \; | sort | uniq -d -w 33
```

it will list duplicated md5sum and file names.

if my guessing was wrong, just ignore my answer.

Comment: He is asking the same thing all over the net.

Comment: While I appreciate your solution of this particular person's XY problem, this is unrelated to the question asked and so useless as a resource going forward.

Answer (score 1):

`md5sum` (at least the version in GNU coreutils) doesn't provide options for controlling the output format. You should change your awk script to treat the characters 0...15 as the md5sum, and characters 18 to the end of the line as the filename. If you really need the particular format, you should parse the output of `md5sum`. For example:

```
user@host:~$ md5sum "/dev/null" | python -c 'import sys; s = sys.stdin.read(); print s[0:32] + "|" + s[34:],'
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e|/dev/null
```

Also, you should be enclosing the argument to `md5sum` in quotes (`md5sum "$i"`). As written, the script will fail if there are any filenames containing spaces or special characters.